# How to fetch database values sotred in asset folder?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created database by sqlite magager-firefox adons and I have saved that database in my asset folder. I don't know how to fetch the values of that database. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a reusable library for this nowadays, [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), that assists you in packaging a database with your app and copying it into position when you first need it. You cannot query a database directly from your project's assets, though, which is why you need something like `SQLiteAssetHelper`.